# Alternative for send() for creating dynamic link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eval, send

I am playing around with dynamic links for objects and came up with this:

```
link = link_to 'New', send("new_#{params[:controller].singularize}_path")
```

I am specially interested in the `send` part. Is this a good practise and are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better than other to use send. eval is less good.

But in the link_to case you can use an url_for format

```
link = link_to 'New', {:controller => params[:controller], :action => 'new'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to set explicitly the controller. You can do like so :

```
link = link_to 'New', action: 'new'
```